# Unexpected color mapping when using IndexColorModel

Tags: java, image-processing, bufferedimage, alpha-transparency, colormap

I have some old Java 6 code to convert a black, white, and transparent image to a new color palette with two opaque colors and a transparent color.

```
int[] cmap = { 0x000000, 0x6c4eee, 0x2e00a4 };
IndexColorModel icm = new IndexColorModel(2, cmap.length, cmap, 0, false, 0, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);

BufferedImage orig = loadImage("image.png");
BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(orig.getWidth(), orig.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED, icm);

Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) result.getGraphics();
try {
    g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
    g.drawImage(orig, 0, 0, null);
} finally {
    g.dispose();
}
```

The source image has only black, white, and transparent pixels.  I would expect that transparent pixels would be mapped to the transparent color, white pixels would be mapped to the lighter color (`0x6c4eee`), and black pixels would be mapped to the darker color (`0x2e00a4`).  However, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43628358/drawimage-with-indexcolormodel-with-transparency), both black and transparent pixels in the source image are mapped to the transparent color.

There are a couple of strange things about this that make me wonder if this is a bug:

- If I manually use `BufferedImage.setRGB()` to set a pixel color in the new image, the color is translated as expected.
- This code used to work as expected on my old computer.

Can anyone explain this behavior?  Is this a bug?  And if so, is there a known workaround?  (I haven't been able to find documentation of how color transformations with an `IndexColorModel` are supposed to work in the first place, so it's hard to tell what the "correct" behavior really is.)

**Update:** I found [this OpenJDK bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068826) which seemed to be similar, but the suggested workaround (using the `BufferedImage(ColorModel, WritableRaster, boolean, Hashtable)`) didn't fix the issue for me.

Comment: Should the colors be 0xff6c4eee etc? Where is the alpha channel specified?

Comment: @samgak It's not specified (the `false` parameter to the ICM constructor). Instead, the color at index 0 (the second `0` parameter in the ICM constructor) is assumed to be fully transparent (regardless of what color it actually has in the map `cmap`). But it's worth testing, and if it makes a difference, it is a bug.

Comment: One more thing that might make a difference is the new color management system (CMS) that was introduced in later Java versions (LittleCMS). I've seen various small differences due to this. You could try reverting the CMS to the legacy Kodak CMS (works only on Oracle JREs), by specifying the system property: `-Dsun.java2d.cmm=sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider` on the command line. Again, if that makes a difference, I think it should be reported as a bug.